# Passing GET variables in a PHP CURL POST request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to pass variable value (sample=1000)  to a link

```
http://10.219.5.109:9000/mean
```

and it should finally look like

```
http://10.219.5.109:9000/mean?sample=1000
```

I am using following php code but it seems variable are not getting passed properly as it not running.

```
$curl_connection =curl_init('http://10.219.5.109:9000/mean');
$post_string='sample=1000';
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
```

How can i properly bind variables to link?

Comment: `$curl_connection = curl_init('http://10.219.5.109/mean?'.$post_string)`

Comment: The last `.''` are redundant @Kisaragi

Comment: @Albzi Thanks, updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are doing a GET request, so the post variables will never be send to the server. You could just add the parameters as a query string to the url.

Like so:

```
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://10.219.5.109:9000/mean?sample=1000');
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
```

If you want the data to be dynamic, you can do it like this:

```
$post_string = 'sample=1000';
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://10.219.5.109:9000/mean?' . $post_string);
```

Comment: Thanks!!..It working perfectly.. But how can i bind more variables in it ? I have 4 variables  "size", "height", "weight"  and "class". Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Yes, you just have to put an `&` between them. So it becomes `sample=1000&size=15&height=0` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://10.219.5.109:9000/mean?sample=1000',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Simple cURL'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Sample value can be also set through variable.